# AWS EC2 Angular 5 ng serve not connecting via browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm-install, angular5

I managed to get my Angular 5 app running on AWS EC2 Ubuntu...

Started standard Ubuntu instance, used PuTTy to shell in, installed node, entered the next 4 "magic lines"...

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

made my company dir, did a global npm install for @angular/cli, cloned my git, changed dir to project subfolder, did a local npm install for @angular/cli, and then ran npm install for my project. At this point, I was able to run ng serve with no serious errors during any of the above steps! whew!

It showed it was happily running on port 4200. I even checked with netstat -anp | grep 4200 and also with telnet 127.0.0.1 4200. Yep all working.

Then I went into the AWS dashboard, and created a security group for my instance, turning on HTTP and HTTPS with default values, and then adding one custom TCP rule for Port Range 4200 open to Anywhere, and saved. However, when I go to a browser and enter http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4200 (where the x's are the public IP that AWS assigned to my instance), I get a "can’t establish a connection to the server" error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, please note that the built-in webserver in ng-cli is **not intended** to be used in production. I **strongly** advise you to find a better solution if this is for production.

In order to access the site from other devices/ over the internet, you have to instruct ng-cli to serve it at the correct IP-adress. You can do that by running `ng serve --host x.x.x.x`.

It will probably work if you enter your servers LAN-IP (depending on your setup). You can find it by running `ifconfig`.

However, since you are hosting a static website, an alternative solution is to simply host the app on S3. To do that, run `ng build --prod` and upload the dist-folder to AWS S3. They have a tutorial for that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html).

Alternatively, you can use something like Apache or nginx to serve your compiled app from your EC2-instance.

Comment: I am going to check your answer as the right one even though the second half didn't fit our ultimate solution. In our case, we ended up using Elastic Beanstalk instead of S3 as our site is not static, and we didn't end up using EC2 where we set everything up. The trick was in NOT selecting node.js as our server, and using Tomcat instead. For anyone else doing this, you can read more in this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693139/angular-5-create-an-application-source-bundle-for-aws-ec2).

Comment: Yes, that is probably a better solution then. :-)

Comment: @AppDreamer, I want to host my Angular 5 dynamic application in EC2 or Beanstalk. Can you please help me on sharing what things you have tried?

Answer (score 4):

You need to check few things in your EC2 instance first

- First check that port 4200 or any port that you want to use for Angular is added in security group to accept the traffic.
- After allowing the port run ng serve with correct domain name or Public DNS shown in EC2 Instance for example

> "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"

**Hot Fix:**

If you are getting this error with localhost:4200 you can try `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

To add specific port you can execute the command as follows: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200`

Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ng serve  --port 4202 --host 0.0.0.0 --publicHost ec2-your-public-host-link.com
```

Comment: This worked for me when I was facing a similar error while deploying in an AWS EC2 instance. Thanks!