# Angular - can not serve on EC2

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-ec2

I created Angular app on EC2 (RHEL 7) with `ng new app1` and tried to serve it with:

```
ng new app1
cd app1
ng serve --port=4200
```

When I go to url: `IP:4200` - getting following error:

```
Exception:  tcp_error
Exception details:  A communication error occurred: "Connection refused"
```

But when I try with NodeJS on the same server and same port - I can see the result on the same `IP:4200` . NodeJS code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World 3!');
});
app.listen(4200, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4500!');
});
```

What could be wrong with Angular and EC2? I can run the exact same Angular code on my local computer and when go to `localhost:4200` - I can see results (but not from EC2 `IP:4200`).

Comment: Does `netstat -ntlp` show in both cases an application running on port 4200? (Pay also attention to the IP, if one listens on `0.0.0.0` while the other in `127.0.0.1` for example). And in which program are you seeing that exception message you posted?

Comment: The one that is showing error is Angular (`connection refused`) and when I run `netstat -ntlp` for Angular (not working) is showing for `Local Address` as `127.0.0.1:4200` and for NodeJS is showing `:::4200`. What should I do next?

Comment: Have you configured the firewall inbound rule? and is this a production mode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS EC2 Angular 5 ng serve not connecting via browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779923/aws-ec2-angular-5-ng-serve-not-connecting-via-browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the output of `netstat`, Angular's server is configured to listen only for connections that target the ip `127.0.0.1`.

But connections from outside will target a different IP, so you need to pass that other IP with the `--host` param. Or, to make it easier, use the IP `0.0.0.0` which means "every IP that this host responds to".

So the command should be like:

```
ng serve --port=4200 --host=0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use "netstat -na | grep :4200" to check whether 4200 port is open
2. use telnet 127.0.0.1 4200 to check whether you can connect to this port via internal ip
3. use telnet [external ip] 4200 to check whether you can connect this port via external ip

To locate the issue.